# Django template doesn't show the entire list in my view

Tags: python, django, list, templates, view

My view function printing all of the list in terminal but it is show just 1 line in template(web ,html page) how to fix my code for like terminal output

/views.py

```
def snmpWALK(request):

    if request.method=='GET':
        host= 'localhost'
        oid = '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2'
        for (errorIndication,
            errorStatus,
            errorIndex,
            varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                                CommunityData('public'),
                                UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
                                ContextData(),
                                ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
                                lookupMib=False,
                                lexicographicMode=False):

            if errorIndication:
                print(errorIndication, file=sys.stderr)
                break

            elif errorStatus:
                print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                                    errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'), file=sys.stderr)
            break

            else:

                MyList = []
                for varBind in varBinds:

                    thing='%s = %s' % varBind
                    MyList.append(thing)

            print (MyList)


    return render(request, 'snmpWALK.html', {'MyList':MyList})
```

/snmpWALK.html

```
{% block content %} 
{{MyList}}
{% endblock %}
```

terminal printing

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.1 = 1.3.6.1.6.3.11.3.1.1']

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.2 = 1.3.6.1.6.3.15.2.1.1']

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.3 = 1.3.6.1.6.3.10.3.1.1']

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.4 = 1.3.6.1.6.3.1']

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.5 = 1.3.6.1.6.3.16.2.2.1']

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.6 = 1.3.6.1.2.1.49']

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.7 = 1.3.6.1.2.1.4']

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.8 = 1.3.6.1.2.1.50']

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.9 = 1.3.6.1.6.3.13.3.1.3']

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.10 = 1.3.6.1.2.1.92']

web printing

['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.10 = 1.3.6.1.2.1.92']

Comment: The line `results ='%s = %s' % varBind` is outside the `for` loop therefore it only contains the latest result.

Comment: no I'm trying in for loop again same output

Comment: Simply indenting it won't work. You are overwriting the variable with the latest value. You should initialise it to an empty string before the loop, then concatenate new values as you go. Better yet use a list instead of a string.

Comment: All the information I received comes as 1 string variable.When I define a list index is actually 0

Comment: Can you please post your **latest** code, your expected result and the result you are currently seeing?

Comment: I sent.I mean , with snmpwalk command ,me turns one string after I splitting this string and it is show like terminal printing but web printing it just show one line(actually last line ).When I define a list, all information in one string and again all information one index in list so index number of elements again one and web printing still last line @Selcuk

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Your terminal output is multiple lists whereas it must be a single list. Almost certainly your indentation is different than you post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation certainly makes your code very hard to read.  I suspect the reason that you are seeing multiple lists is that your `print` call is within the `for` loop.  Here's how to fix that:

```
def snmpWALK(request):
    all_lists = []
    if request.method=='GET':
        host= 'localhost'
        oid = '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2'        
        for t in nextCmd(
                SnmpEngine(),
                CommunityData('public'),
                UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
                ContextData(),
                ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
                lookupMib=False,
                lexicographicMode=False):
            # I broke this up for purposes of formatting 
            # on SO.  normally, I would just stick these in
            # the for loop above.
            errorIndication, errorStatus = t[0], t[1]
            errorIndex, varBinds = t[2], t[3]
            if errorIndication:
                print(errorIndication, file=sys.stderr)
                break
            elif errorStatus:
                print('%s at %s' % (
                    errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                    errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'
                ), file=sys.stderr)
                break
            else:
                MyList = []
                for varBind in varBinds:
                    thing='%s = %s' % varBind
                    MyList.append(thing)
            # this is within the for loop!!!
            print(MyList)
            all_lists.append(MyList)
    return render(request, 'snmpWALK.html', {'MyList': all_lists})
```

In general, your code was fairly hard to read for those of us that like to help out on SO because (1) it was improperly indented (you can see the `break` statements in the OP) and (2) it didn't follow PEP8.  YMMV if you want to follow these conventions / suggestions, it's just a lot easier to help you if you do.